# Finding a calculation formula to convert different units

Tags: calculator, unit-of-measure

A solution to my problem definitely must exist somewhere online, but I definitely don't know the right terminology to find it.
Essentially I am making a quick script to convert measuring units of oil (cst and wt) both of which are brand specific so are difficult to calculate the 'weight' of the oil.
I have this basic information for the two oil units. Is it possible to find a formula to convert between these two units based on this information?

\begin{align*}
1000\mathrm{cst} &= 80\mathrm{wt} \\
650\mathrm{cst} &= 50\mathrm{wt} \\
200\mathrm{cst} &= 20\mathrm{wt} \\
100\mathrm{cst} &= 10\mathrm{wt} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Would you prefer (1) a simple formula that gives approximately the correct answer (that is, not exactly the correct answer); or (2) a more complicated formula that gives **exactly** the correct answer?

Comment: Linear regression will work since they are not exactly proportional. You may also just want to take the most common conversion factor (10cst = 1wt).

Comment: Doesn't need to be precise. Simple, roughly lands on the matching figures. Maybe near enough to then also get rounded, say 700cst rounded to 50wt or 55wt?

Comment: 10cst = 1wt is what I initially tried but it progressively gets out of sync and then becomes incorrect. Was hoping maths would have a way of solving this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to know exactly how the amounts in cst units are converted to the amounts in wt units.
Either the relationship is non-linear or there is some rounding going on.

If the relationship is based on $1\,\mathrm{cst} = k\,\mathrm{wt}$
but the result of the calculation is then rounded to the nearest multiple of $10,$
there are various values of $k$ that might fit the given results.
An obvious choice would be $k = 0.08$, which is exactly for the first conversion and also works out for the other three conversions with rounding to the nearest multiple of $10.$
But a factor $k = 0.082$ would also work.

I don't think there is any way to reconcile the given figures with a linear factor with the result rounded to the nearest multiple of $5.$
If the rule for conversion had that form, the first equation says $k$ must be less than $0.0825$ (otherwise the linear conversion would be from $1000$ to at least $82.5$ which then would round to at least $85$), but the third equation says $k$ must be at least $0.0875$, since otherwise the linear conversion would give less than $17.5$, which would round to $15$ or less.

Conversion in the other direction would represent only a guess as to what the weight in cst is, since rounding causes multiple possible cst weights to be represented by the same wt weight.